# Adding Bulk users to Active Directory with .CSV Import?

Tags: csv, vbscript, active-directory

Hello and thanks for looking at my Problem.

I am new to AD and need help importing bulk users to AD.

Here is a link to the csv i wish to import; dont worry, it is all random data and there is no personal information stored.

http://www.mediafire.com/?s2j37lsps83o86s

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Updated :

Bulk Users CSV Import with PowerShell : http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/Create-Bulk-AD-Users-from-CSV-using-Powershell-Script.html

VBScript :

```
' CreateBulkADUsersFromCSVFile.vbs
' Sample VBScript to create a AD Users from CSV file .
' Author: http://www.morgantechspace.com/
' ------------------------------------------------------' 
Option Explicit 

' Variables needed for LDAP connection 
Dim objRootLDAP 
Dim objContainer 

' Variables needed for CSV File Information
Dim varFileName
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile

' Holding variables for user information import from CSV file 
Dim varSamAccountName,varFirstName,varLastName
Dim newUserFields 

Dim objNewUser 
Dim varDomain 

Const ForReading = 1

' Modify this name to match your company's AD domain 
varDomain="workdomain.local" 

' Create a connection to the Active Directory Users container. 
Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE") 

' You can give your own OU like LDAP://OU=TestOU instead of LDAP://cn=Users
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://cn=Users," & objRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

' Specify the csv file full path.
varFileName = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewUsers.csv"

' Open the file for reading.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(varFileName, ForReading)

' Read the first line - csv columns -not needed for our proceess
objFile.ReadLine

' Skip the error while creating new user...(i.e- user already exists)
on error resume next

' Read the file and create new user.
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    ' Splits prioperty values.
    newUserFields = Split(objFile.ReadLine,",")
    varSamAccountName = newUserFields(0)
    varFirstName = newUserFields(1) 
    varLastName = newUserFields(2) 


' Create new User account 
Set objNewUser = objContainer.Create("User","cn="&varFirstName&" "&varLastName) 

objNewUser.put "sAMAccountName",lcase(varSamAccountName) 
objNewUser.put "givenName",varFirstName 
objNewUser.put "sn",varLastName 
objNewUser.put "UserPrincipalName",lcase(varSamAccountName)&"@"&varDomain 
objNewUser.put "DisplayName",varFirstName&" "&varLastName 
objNewUser.put "name",lcase(varSamAccountName) 
objNewUser.put "description","This user was created from csv file using vbscript"

objNewUser.SetInfo 
objNewUser.Put "pwdLastSet", 0 

' Enable the user account 
objNewUser.AccountDisabled = FALSE
objNewUser.SetInfo 
Loop

MsgBox("Active Directory users created successfully from CSV file using VBScript.")

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a script/program to handle this task in an automated manner.  It is frowned upon to just come in and ask people to do your work for you as this site is really focused on people that need help with something they are doing.

Ideally you would post your question with the code you are working from, and what is going wrong; not just ask someone to write a program for you.

I suspect that if you don't change the question, it will/should be deleted.